# Delete a Picture & thumbnails with sorl.thumbnail (Django)

Tags: python, django

I am working with Python 2.7, Django 1.9 and sorl.thumbnail.

I cannot manage to create a view to delete in one time the original picture file, the Picture entry in the database, the  thumbnail pictures generated by sorl.thulbnail, and the thumbnail_kvstore entry in the database.

Here is my Picture model:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    exiflnglat = models.PointField(dim=3, geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('upload-new', )
```

And here is my view:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import delete

def deletepicnthumbs(request, pk):
    allpicfromuser = Picture.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    pictodelete = allpicfromuser.get(id=pk)
    delete(pictodelete)
    return redirect(adddetails)
```

This view does not delete anything.. What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use the `delete` method from sorl to delete an instance of the `Picture` model instead of the picture itself.

This code should work :

````
from sorl.thumbnail import delete

def deletepicnthumbs(request, pk):
    pictodelete = Picture.objects.get_object_or_404(id=pk, user=request.user)
    # Delete the thumbnails, as well as the original image
    # If you want to keep the original image, pass ```delete_file=False```
    delete(pictodelete.file)
    # We use Django's method to delete the Picture instance, if needed
    pictodelete.delete()
    return redirect(adddetails)
````

Hope this helps,
Adela